# Python input validation?

Tags: python, user-input

I have a simple input validation code asking the user for either ACT or SAT.

```
test=input("Are you taking SAT or ACT?..")
while test!=("SAT" or "ACT"):
    print("error")
    test=input("Are you taking SAT or ACT?..")
```

It seems to work correctly for "SAT" which is in front on line 2, but not ACT! When I type in ACT in the module it will print "error" like it was false. What is my flaw here? Logic? Syntax? Semantic? What can I do to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this statement is valid:

```
test!=("SAT" or "ACT")
```

You may use

```
test != "SAT" and test != "ACT"
```

Or use `in` operator:

```
test=input("Are you taking SAT or ACT?..")
while test not in ("SAT", "ACT"):
    print("error")
    test=input("Are you taking SAT or ACT?..")
```

Comment: The statement is perfectly valid, but it does not yield the expected results. Operators in programming languages work in a very simple, well-defined way. On the other hand this means, that they cannot be used like in conversation language. Compare for example this pseudocode "if test is not a or b" (conversational) to "if (test is not a) and (test is not b)" (strict).

Comment: Yes. You are right. I meant by "not valid" that the statement doesn't mean anything useful here, because it doesn't achieve what OP wanted, and because `"SAT" or "ACT"` always yield the same thing, "SAT".

Comment: thank you, I get it now-- no matter ACT or SAT, the while loop will always be true when I use "or".

Comment: @PupWatthanawong In fact, when you enter "SAT" the condition of the `while` loop will evaluate to `False`, because `"SAT" or "ACT"` always evaluates to `"SAT"`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `("SAT" or "ACT")` evaluates to `"SAT"` since it basically evaluates the `OR` operation on two strings. In order to fix the issue, this is what you can do:

```
while(1):
    test = input("Are you taking SAT or ACT")
    if test in ("SAT", "ACT"):
        break

    print("Error")
```

Comment: Using the `not in` operator would make for a smaller change. Also, no need for parenthesis in a `while True:`.

Answer (score 0):

Teverse the condition from `test!=("SAT" or "ACT")` to `test==("SAT" or "ACT")` or you can use `IN` as explained by Kshitij Saraogi.